# How can I renew the SSL certificate used on our Exchange server?

Tags: exchange-2010, ssl-certificate, x509

According to the MSDN article [Renew an Exchange Certificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332322(v=exchg.141).aspx), I'm supposed to use

> `Get-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint 'AD19B141228C7CF98B5F78DCED978B7C45E15434' | New-ExchangeCertificate -GenerateRequest -PrivateKeyExportable $true`

This will generate a CSR for me, which I send to our SSL certificate reseller through their SSL certificate renewal website. That site then promptly returns the following error:

```
[20022] CSR Country code invalid
```

Which isn't surprising, because the CSR doesn't contain any country code as far as I can tell.

In the past years, I've just bought a *new* certificate and replaced the old one. But I'd really like to understand what's going wrong with this renewal process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is supposed to grab your existing certificate, and make a new CSR with the same information (and I think a new key?).

Take a look at the output of `Get-ExchangeCertificate` and see if it contains a country code (`C=XX` appears in the subject DN of the certificate where XX is a 2-letter country code).  If it does not, your old certificate didn't have one and you should make a new one with it.  If it does, you might have found a bug and you won't be able to use this method.

Either way, it seems you should create a fresh new CSR.

Comment: Indeed. The Subject doesn't contain a country code either. Which is confusing, since I bought this certificate from the same reseller. So they're issuing certificates without a country code and then require it to be present when you renew? That's a bit confusing

Comment: They may have changed their policy to better align with that of other CAs, or they might just be applying it inconsistently.